# How cloudfront works?

Tags: cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I'm planning to Implement CDN(Content Delivery Network) of Amazon which is known as CloudFront in ASP.NET MVC3 with c#.
I've googled about it but little bit confuse about few things mentions below.

1. Is it compulsory that we have to uploads all static resources to CDN Network first and then we can use or Is it manageable by Amazon to crawl site static resources which is predefine folder or directory of sites?
2. Is Amazon automatic update its copies when we anything change in static resources or every time we have to upload updated resources to CDN network.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. CloudFront is basically a cache. When a resource is first accessed it contacts your origin servers for a copy, you don't need to preload anything. If you are serving static resources the best way is to give it an S3 bucket with the resources in.
2. If your origin servers set HTTP cache control headers then CloudFront will use them to determine how often to check for updated files. Otherwise you can set a default timeout in the CloudFront settings. Here is [Amazon's documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html).

Comment: That means this is done automatically and no need to use any API or FTP to upload static contents. right?

Comment: Yes you just need to tell it where the content is, you can't upload it directly. You can select which content to include via the web interface or add it via the API.

Comment: what do you recommend?Amazon Cloud Front or MaxCdn?